# Create a combined list of random order from a fixed number of items

Tags: python, random

Say I have 3 different items being `A`, `B` and `C`. I want to create a combined list containing `NA` copies of `A`, `NB` copies of `B` and `NC` copies of `C` in **random orders**. So the results should look like this:

`finalList = [A, C, A, A, B, C, A, C,...]`

Is there a clean way to get around this using `np.random.rand` Pythonically? If not, any other packages besides `numpy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need numpy for that. You can use the `random` builtin package:

```
import random
na = nb = nc = 5
l = ['A'] * na + ['B'] *nb + ['C'] * nc
random.shuffle(l)
```

list `l` will look something like:

```
['A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A']
```

Comment: What if there are 20 elements to be repeated in 20 different ways?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, in that case you can use a loop or use your way to create it. Anyway, I don't think that this was the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a list of tuples. Each tuple should contain a character and desired frequency. Then you can create a list where each element is repeated with specified frequency and finally shuffle it using `random.shuffle`

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [('A',3),('B',5),('C',10)]
>>> a = [val for val, freq in l for i in range(freq)]
>>> random.shuffle(a)
>>> ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is very much possible (and simple) with numpy. You'll have to create an array with your unique elements, repeat each element a specified number of times using `np.repeat` (using an `axis` argument makes this possible), and then shuffle with `np.random.shuffle`.

Here's an example with `NA` as `1`, `NB` as `2`, and `NC` as `3`.

```
a = np.array([['A', 'B', 'C']]).repeat([1, 2, 3], axis=1).squeeze()
np.random.shuffle(a)
```

```
print(a)
array(['B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Note that it is simpler to use numpy, specifying an array of unique elements and repeats, versus a pure python implementation when you have a large number of unique elements to repeat.

Comment: in pure python implementation you can use a list of tuples to specify character and its frequency like `[('A', 10)]`. This will be feasible for large number of characters since you can generate it at run time.

Comment: @GarbageCollector Yep, possible no doubt, but slower than a numpy implementation was all I was trying to get at. Still, passed you an upvote.

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate. And yes about the speed optimisation you are absolutely correct. If OP is ok with using `numpy`, then this should be the accepted answer.